# Bibtex saying I couldn't open style file .bst

Tags: bibtex

When using bibtex (out of texmaker) I get the error "I couldn't open style file spbasic.bst".
With spmpsci instead of spbasic it's working, but the situation for both is the same:
`spmpsci.bst` is in folder

```
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/spmpsci
```

and
`spbasic.bst` is in

```
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/spbasic
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\cite{Bernoulli1713}.

\bibliographystyle{spbasic}
\bibliography{Bibliographie}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: update by

> sudo texhash /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist

Checking if it was successful by

> kpsewhich spbasic.bst

This should result in giving the path.

Comment: How do I sort that out if this error occurs in Overlead?

Comment: @PWillms Sorry, I don't know. I am not using overleaf but tex maker.